# Searching within NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an NSString that is of the following pattern:

```
Hello


No.: 123456789123
Age: 21

Country: xxx
```

How can I search within said string so that i get "123456789123" as a new string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rangeOfString:` will return the range of the string you are searching for. To extract this range from the original string, use `substringWithRange:`.

*Edit: If the string you are looking for is unknown (and you want to search for the "No." string and extract everything that comes behind it, `NSScanner` is one good way to go.*

Answer (score 1):

I think `[yourString substringWithRange:[yourString rangeOfString:@"123456789123"]]` should give you what you want.

Presumably you have a variable with the value "123456789123", in which case you would do `[yourString substringWithRange:[yourString rangeOfString:otherString]]`.

For more information, see the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).