# How to get substring of NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

If I want to get a value from the NSString `@"value:hello World:value"`, what should I use?

The return value I want is `@"hello World"`.

Comment: possible duplicate [search within NSstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771211/search-within-nsstring) or [Search through NSString using Regular Expression.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear what your asking.  There's no indication at all of exactly what is wanted here.  Do you want to just return `"hello World"`?  `return @"hello World"`.  Do you want to return just what's between colons?  Do you want to strip everything left of the left-most colon and everything right of the right-most colon?  There is no clearly defined input-output criteria for this question (as we see with the resulting list of questions that all solve the problem with a wild array of approaches).

Answer (score 163, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
NSString *haystack = @"value:hello World:value";
NSString *haystackPrefix = @"value:";
NSString *haystackSuffix = @":value";
NSRange needleRange = NSMakeRange(haystackPrefix.length,
                                  haystack.length - haystackPrefix.length - haystackSuffix.length);
NSString *needle = [haystack substringWithRange:needleRange];
NSLog(@"needle: %@", needle); // -> "hello World"
```

**Option 2:**

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^value:(.+?):value$" options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:haystack options:NSAnchoredSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, haystack.length)];
NSRange needleRange = [match rangeAtIndex: 1];
NSString *needle = [haystack substringWithRange:needleRange];
```

This one might be a bit over the top for your rather trivial case though.

**Option 3:**

```
NSString *needle = [haystack componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][1];
```

This one creates three temporary strings and an array while splitting.

---

All snippets assume that what's searched for is actually contained in the string.

Comment: It cried on NSAnchoredSearch... maybe NSMatchingAnchored is better.

Answer (score 76):

Here's a slightly less complicated answer:

```
NSString *myString = @"abcdefg";
NSString *mySmallerString = [myString substringToIndex:4];
```

See also substringWithRange and substringFromIndex

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question (how to get a substring from the middle of a string).

Comment: what does that return

Answer (score 18):

Here's a simple function that lets you do what you are looking for:

```
- (NSString *)getSubstring:(NSString *)value betweenString:(NSString *)separator
{
    NSRange firstInstance = [value rangeOfString:separator];
    NSRange secondInstance = [[value substringFromIndex:firstInstance.location + firstInstance.length] rangeOfString:separator];
    NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(firstInstance.location + separator.length, secondInstance.location);

    return [value substringWithRange:finalRange];
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *myName = [self getSubstring:@"This is my :name:, woo!!" betweenString:@":"];
```

Comment: In case it's illuminating, I can tell you my reason for voting up the other answer. I would rather write two lines of code than six.

Comment: The problem is that those two lines of code only solve a specific case that will never exist for anyone -- probably not even for the person that asked it.

Comment: `getSubstring:…` should be called `substringInString:…` as you're not passing a substring to it and methods starting with `get…` are usually expected to be passed a buffer pointer to write to. `substringFromIndex:` creates an intermediate substring, which is unnecessary, that's what `rangeOfString:options:range:` is for. Last by wrapping the unsafe snippet in a supposedly generic method you're masking a bug: If the separator exists a single or less times in the string you'll get an out of range exception.

Answer (score 14):

Use this also

```
NSString *ChkStr = [MyString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 26)];
```

Note - Your `NSMakeRange(start, end)` should be `NSMakeRange(start, end- start)`;

Answer (score 13):

Here is a little combination of @Regexident Option 1 and @Garett answers, to get a powerful string cutter between a prefix and suffix, with MORE...ANDMORE words on it.

```
NSString *haystack = @"MOREvalue:hello World:valueANDMORE";
NSString *prefix = @"value:";
NSString *suffix = @":value";
NSRange prefixRange = [haystack rangeOfString:prefix];
NSRange suffixRange = [[haystack substringFromIndex:prefixRange.location+prefixRange.length] rangeOfString:suffix];
NSRange needleRange = NSMakeRange(prefixRange.location+prefix.length, suffixRange.location);
NSString *needle = [haystack substringWithRange:needleRange];
NSLog(@"needle: %@", needle);
```

Comment: Now this works! I tried Regixident's option 1, it didn't work for me. I can't think why. I've been searching for a solution to get a string inside a ```<i></i>``` tags in my project to make those strings italic. :)