# I am having a String/server issue in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I am receiving this response from my sever but am unsure how to parse it out to and easy string to quantify.

What I am receiving  "["yes"]"

What I want @"yes"

I am sure it is simple im just tired

Comment: if you're tired, it might be worthwhile to just take a nap and come back to this fresh tomorrow...

Comment: And when you come back to this tomorrow, perhaps you can more clearly describe the nature of the server response. "["yes"]" doesn't make sense. Do you mean a five character string "[yes]"? Or are you getting quotation marks in the response, too? I'm not clear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *stringToCheck = @"['Yes']";
NSString *value = [foo substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [foo length] - 2 * 2)];
```

Sources that is good for you to check:

1. [how-to-get-substring-of-nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676106/how-to-get-substring-of-nsstring)
2. [search-within-nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771211/search-within-nsstring)

Comment: Thank you, your clarity has replaced my blurriness